# Inserting text to HTML <input/> field through Javascript event

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom-events

I am looking for a method to insert text to input field without using DOM APIs. But what I am trying to find is to make a new `input` event through Javascript and dispatch the event to an input field. So that the text value that is tied to the event would be populated in the input.

I tried to set a value to the `data` property to the `input` event. But that didn't work. Please see the code below:

```
const nameField = document.querySelector('#name');
const event = new Event('input');
event.data = '1234'; 
nameField.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Please share your knowledges if you know how to do so.

Comment: `I am looking for a method to insert text to input field without using DOM APIs` why? What's the goal here? Why not use `document.querySelector('#name').value = "1234";`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have an event listener for your custom input event. That way you're dispatching an event without actually handling it.

Try this:

```js
const nameField = document.querySelector('#name');
nameField.addEventListener("customInput", function(e) {
  e.target.value = e.data
})
const event = new Event('customInput');
event.data = '1234';
nameField.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
```

Comment: You are still setting the text value through Javascript `e.target.value = e.data`. What I want here is to use native `input` event without any custom Javascript to set the input field's value.

Comment: Then I'm afraid this is not possible. The input event fires as soon as the value property of the target element has changed and is not meant to be used to alter it.